# WordPress scruity issue - Totally disable all comments by CSS --- secure enough?

Tags: comments, security

I have a website in which I want to totally disable, by principle, all comment-publishing windows / all comment functionality.

I can give a CSS directive like:

```
#comment-section, .respond {display: none}
```

Is it a secure way of removing any comment functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously that will not remove comment functionality, just will not display relevant comment related data on the front end.

Comment: But it will prevent humans and robots to post any comment, basically. Wouldn't it?

Comment: no it will not, might just make it harder

Comment: Crap. I guess that CSS (or JS) both aren't enough and I must do it from PHP?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just turn off enable discussion on new articles in Settings > Discussion and make sure Comments are disabled for existin pages and posts.